# What value is stored when a form field is left empty?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

What value does rails read for fields that are left empty when filling out a bootstrap form?

The form asks for the period during which a person was working. The period is stored as a string. This is about work life experience, so it needs to be possible to say "not specified". (A previous developer's decision to solve it that way.)

Recently it was decided that we needed to sort a person's work life experience according to when they ended their employment. To do this I added the column `end_date` and added this line to the print

```
<% @profile.traits.order('end_date DESC NULLS FIRST').each do |trait| %>
```

This doesn't seem to work as expected. It seems when both start and end date are provided they are ordered as expected. However, when an end date is not specified it ends up at the bottom on the list rather than at the top, UNLESS the entry was created prior to the addition of the `end_date` column. So the order becomes old entries, new entries with end date, and finally new entries without end date.

Because of this I suspect that old entries are given NULL as value when a new column is added. But I have no idea what value is stored when a field is left empty in a form, as it doesn't seem to be NULL? And is there a way to specify so that these come at the top rather than bottom?

Comment: It seems like your question is something like "How do I sort records so that..." rather than "What value is stored when..." FWIW, you might consider changing the title of your question and putting your *actual* question near the top to help folks determine if they might be able to help you.

Comment: Sorry if I phrased it poorly, but what I really want to know is what is stored in the database in the column "end_date" when I leave that field in the form empty!

Comment: Why not just look at a record and see?

Comment: Because I apparently forgot you could even do that... my bad. It stores an empty string "" when the field is left empty.

Comment: Riiiiiiighteoooooo! Well done.